# Display result of parse XML in UIViewController, GDataXML

Tags: objective-c, gdataxml

i parsed a XML with GDataXML but now i need display the result in a UILabel, i'm working with a UIViewController.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the issue... what do require here, if u have the data then display in UILabel, after receiving..

Comment: i have mylabel.text = [data_from_xml attributeForName=@"attribute"]; and it don't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check wether u r getting the exact data as per requirement..

we have the methods to retrieve the value:

```
- (NSString*) stringValueForAttribute: (NSString*)attributeName;
- (BOOL) boolValueForAttribute: (NSString*)attributeName;
- (NSInteger) integerValueForAttribute: (NSString*)attributeName;
```

get the corresponding value in a string, as

```
NSString* str = [data_from_xml stringValueForAttribute:@"attribute"];
```

print the value for cross check

```
NSlog(@"%@", str);
```

then display on label

```
mylabel.text = str;
```